# SQL in Access 2013 syntax error

Tags: ms-access-2013

I've just recently started trying to learn SQL and I cannot seem to figure out my syntax error is. MS Access 2013 keeps telling me that there's an error after the NOT EXISTS query. All I am trying to do is display results from one table (table A or PILOT)that do not exist in another table (table B or FLIGHT). Here are my SQL statements (the lot)

```
SELECT A.LIC_NUM
FROM PILOT AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS [

SELECT  *
FROM FLIGHT AS B
WHERE A.LIC_NUM = B.FLIGHT_PILOT

];
```

It bugs me that something so simple could be causing this much of a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if it is MS-Access, please remove MySQL and sql-server tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bracket but you have to use parenthesis

```
SELECT A.LIC_NUM
FROM PILOT AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM FLIGHT AS B
    WHERE A.LIC_NUM = B.FLIGHT_PILOT
);
```

<sub>*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*</sub>